# Multi-antenna extension for NFC

Tags: rf, antenna, nfc

Like many, I am new to this. I am working on a project that would require a short read range over a covered space, like a person's body or table top. Could I make an extended antenna from my smart phone so that it reads over a larger plane quickly at the same short read range of just a couple cm? I've tried searching for relevant post and have found nothing anywhere. I am using a Kyocera torque.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. As adding an extension to this kind of antenna, you would be also extending the antenna itself. Also, the purpose of NFC is focused on "almost touching" the devices, amongst other things, in order not to be communicating to "passing" devices, also NFC enabled. I don't fully understand your application, but maybe there's another RF technology you could use. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Flowmio NFC Patch](http://flomio.com/shop/nfc-readers/nfc-patch-kit/) sounds a bit like what you're looking for.